# Setting up notifications with multiple parameters

Tags: website-design, forms, design, notification

What would be the best approach in allowing a user to be able to set up bulk notifications for themselves that can have various parameters.

The problem is that because the person is setting up various notifications in one go. If all the "options" apply to all the people, then everything is fine. But if you changed your mind, went to edit the notification and wanted to be able to link "Cally" to option 1 and 2 but not 4 anymore. How will you separate them, without changing the set up for the rest of the notifications? and without deleting Cally from the list and creating her a separate notification

Please look at the wireframe provided, as this is complicated to try and explain. But if you were creating this bulk notification would end up with the following separate notifications:

1. Notification on ash based on option 1
2. Notification on ash based on option 2
3. Notification on ash based on option 4
4. Notification on cally based on option 1
5. Notification on cally based on option 2
6. Notification on cally based on option 4
7. Notification on Lauren based on option 1
8. Notification on Lauren based on option 2
9. Notification on Lauren based on option 4

Please look at the wireframe as it is complicated to try and explain without using the real parameters that the notification will be based on.

[image]

Comment: Your wireframe shows the interface for _creating_ a batch of notifications, right? Is there separate view that shows a list of existing notifications, once they have been created?

Comment: what is the difference between 'Recipient' and 'Person'? Somebody is either receiving this or not, correct? What are the 2 concepts here?

Comment: Maybe you can find inspiration in the way the macOS [Calendar](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202835) app handles this. When you create a recurring event, you see it repeated in your calendar. After editing one of these recurring events, you are shown a modal dialog giving you the option to cancel, change just this event (automatically disassociating it from other events in the series), or change this event and all future events (splitting these from any past events in the series). I think Google Calendar does something similar too.

Comment: @MattObee, Yes, correct, this page is to create and edit the notification. There is a separate page to view them.

Comment: @MikeM, Recipient is the person that is receiving the notification and person in this case is what the notification is based on.  The recipient in this case will never change as you are always creating a notification for yourself. The use case is a manager of a business that wants to be notified about certain workers in his/her business. So they need to select a person(s) that the reminder is based on, and then they need to be able to select what it is about that person they want to be notified about. What they can be notified about is a static list.

Comment: @MikeM, The problem is that creating in bulk is easy. As you select the people and you select what you what to be reminded of, and what you select eg 'option 1', will then apply to all the people you have selected. But now when you want to edit, if you unselect option 1, it will apply that rule to everyone. But i need a way to only apply that change to the one notification and not all. Does that make more or less sense?

Comment: @RoryO'Kane, That is a good suggestion and I have looked at the way they handle reminders, the problem is the user needs to create many in one go, without changing the others. The way these notifications are built in the backend is that when you create in bulk, you need to edit them in bulk. If you read my previous comments I have tried to explain my problem.

Comment: @ashleigh I've added a mock that will allow you to add and subtract people, and edit options you want to track for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If you use a matrix you can see the relationships of persons to events tracked. You can add or remove persons from the tracking list.

You state in your description:

> If all the "options" apply to all the people, then everything is fine. But if you changed your mind, went to edit the notification and wanted to be able to link "Cally" to option 1 and 2 but not 4 anymore.

Right now the issue is that your current solution doesn't tie the person to the options.

**1. Separate the adding and removing of persons:** Use a simple search and add. Get them into the matrix first.

**2. Manage the tracking of persons and options:** Once they are added to the table (and have a clear relationship to the options to track), you now can select which options to include in the notification.

#### Use good defaults

If you find in testing that most managers want to track all events, then adding a person will add to the table with all options selected for tracking. This can save some extra work.

I put in some fake data to help illustrate. My wording on this is just a first pass, but it allows you to separate the selection of *who is being tracked* vs *what to notify the recipient about*.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1eA5E.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>